# Which frameworks by Microsoft are not well known and are well worth exploring in depth?

Tags: frameworks

It seems that some Microsoft frameworks are only known by name and reputation, not by content or usefulness. Especially with the rise of open source frameworks they sometimes get a bit unpopular.

Which frameworks by Microsoft are not well known and are well worth exploring in depth? What is their reputation and area of usefulness?

Comment: FYI, some frameworks from MS are now open source e.g. MVC, so the two concepts are not mutually exclusive:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it much, but it's a fascinating topic: the [Coordination and Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648752.aspx). It's part of [Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/robotics/default.aspx), which is a pain in terms of installation and licensing, but it's a really neat way of looking at concurrency. Parallel Extensions doesn't quite cover the same ground, as far as I can tell - I'm hoping to see the CCR available as a standalone free library at some point.

The particularly neat aspect from my point of view is representing an asynchronous workflow via continuations in an iterator block. Not as neat as F#, but still pretty nifty.

Comment: I'd second this. CCR stands out for supporting safe coordination of asynchronous event-processing across multiple threads. (Incidentally, some of the CCR primitives can be nicely used from within F# as shown here: http://iodyner.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7B505254340D5E9A!147.entry)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out the stuff they have on Microsoft Research. Like one of the frameworks i find really awesome is the [NaturalSpec](http://code.google.com/p/natural/) which is useful for testing.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft (codename) Phoenix](https://connect.microsoft.com/Phoenix)

Phoenix is an SDK for building compilers, code analysis and optimization tools. When released, it will be used as a back-end for future Microsoft compilers.

The SDK (pre-release) is available the above link.

More information available:

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(compiler_framework))
[Andy Ayers: Understanding the Phoenix Compiler Framework (channel9 video)](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Andy-Ayers-Understanding-the-Phoenix-Compiler-Framework/)